# Randomly getting "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have Created a webjob to crawl my website on Azure which runs in every 10 seconds, the webjob is working fine few months before but now randomly i am getting the below error

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond 81.218.113.171:443     at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)     at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)

I have tried to google it and tried many methods to set on `WebRequest` as stated below

```
WebRequest.proxy = null;
WebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
WebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
WebRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 12;
```

As I am saying the error comes randomly, On crawling 5 to 6 times it comes for once.

Comment: Hi. Did you ever find the cause of this? I've just started having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

How many instances of your web site are running?  It's possible there are (say) 6 instances running, where 5 of them are OK, but the last has stopped running.  The load-balancer doesn't realise the instance is down and is still pushing requests to the 'broken' instance.